# How can find matrix using cofactor matrix and determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra

Cofactor matrix C
$$C=-\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$det(A) = 1$$

How can find matrix A? I'm using cofactor base theory, but I didn't get answer.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:  $A^{-1} = C^T/\det(A)$.

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful to me.